# How to connect to sql server in oracle?

Tags: linux, oracle

I have:
red hat server 6.9 with oracle 11g
windows server 2012 with sql server 2014
navicat 10

Now I can already connect to oracle in sql server.
Using Navicat, Connetc to Sql Server, select from both sql server and oracle together.
The following sql statement works:

```
select emp.Code, emp.Name, dpt.name
from employee emp  --sql server
left join  Ocla..DBName.department dpt on dpt.code=emp.dept_code --oracle
```

I want to do the reverse, which I can't:
Using Navicat, Connetc to Oracle

```
select emp.Code, emp.Name, dpt.name
from department  --oracle
left join  SqlServer..MyDb.employee emp on emp.dept_code=dpt.code --sql server
```

uname -a

```
Linux XXX 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64
```

cat /etc/*release

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
```

sqlplus system/password@oracle
SQL> select * from v$version;

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
...
```

Follow this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

```
[root@XXX ~]# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo  
[root@XXX ~]# ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql17  
[root@XXX ~]# ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install mssql-tools  
[root@XXX ~]# echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile  
[root@XXX ~]# echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc  
[root@XXX ~]# source ~/.bashrc  
[root@XXX ~]# yum install unixODBC-devel  
[root@XXX ~]# vi /etc/odbc.ini  
[root@XXX ~]# sqlcmd -S ip_address -U username -P 'password' -W -Q 'SELECT Name FROM MsSqlDb.dbo.Employee'
```

(List employee's names on sql server database)

Ok, the connection seems works. But how to select ms sql tables with oracle tables together?

I have made a file, but dont know how to use it:
[root@XXX ~]# vi /etc/odbc.ini

```
[MsSqlDb]
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
Description=MSSQL Database
Trace=Yes
Server=192.168.1.10
Port=1433
Database=MyDb
```

I have spend whole day studying...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database link from Oracle to SQL Server. Detailed examples can be found here:

- http://dbaharrison.blogspot.com/2014/12/oracle-talking-to-sql-server-over.html
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/heterogeneous-services-generic-connectivity

At a high level you must (as you have already done) install and configure ODBC; then configure the Oracle listener to point to the ODBC data source; create a tnsnames alias to point to the listener/service; and finally create a database link within Oracle to point to the tnsnames alias.

I have included the links here rather than more explicit steps because the list is rather lengthy, and I do not feel comfortable plagiarizing someone else's explanation, even with the reference.