# Oracle Java store procedure to access POSTGRES and SQLSERVER via JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

I am developing the below java class that makes connections to Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLServer, here the source:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class test {
public static void main (String[] args) {       
    try {
        Connection connORA = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myoracleserver:1521/myschema", "user", "password");
        if (connORA != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to ORACLE");
        }
        
        Connection connPGS = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://IP.of.my.server:5432/mydbname","user","password");
        if (connPGS != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to POSTGRES");
        }       

        Connection connSQS = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP.of.my.server;databaseName=mydbname" ,"user" ,"password");
        if (connSQS != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to SQLSERVER");               
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
}
```

I successfully compile the class with (In $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ I have added *postgresql-42.3.3.jar* and *sqljdbc4-2.0.jar*)

```
javac -cp :$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/* test.java
```

The execution of the class end with the expected output

```
java -cp :$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/* test
Connected to ORACLE
Connected to POSTGRES
Connected to SQLSERVER
```

Now I am wondering if it is possibile to load the class in Oracle DB in order to call the Java via Store procedure so I change the oracle connection string in **jdbc:default:connection:** and do as follow :

```
loadjava -user myoracleuser/muoraclepassword@myoracleschema $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/postgresql-42.3.3.jar
loadjava -user myoracleuser/muoraclepassword@myoracleschema $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar
loadjava -user myoracleuser/muoraclepassword@myoracleschema test.java
```

The execution of the store procedure return this messages:

```
Connected to ORACLE    
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://IP.of.my.server:5432/mydbname
```

I already develop some class that I correctly load and exec via Oracle store procedure but I am quite new with Java and probably I am missing something obvious or trying somthing not allowed. Any suggestion that point me in the right path will be appreciated

Comment: Why are you trying to do this via Java rather than creating a database link?

Comment: @MT0 : do you mean dblink from Oracle to other db? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, create a database link from [Oracle to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971484/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-in-oracle) and from [Oracle to PostgreSQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4269044/connecting-from-oracle-to-postgresql). (From a quick internet search)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/heter/index.html As the area of light expands, so does the perimeter of darkness

Comment: @MT0: Q:"Why are you trying to do this via Java rather than creating a database link?" A: It's free. Is the dblink solution (Oracle Database gateways) under license?